# Using rbind.fill does not fill the correct value

Tags: r, dataframe

I don’t understand how `rbind.fill` works, I guess. I have a data frame called `main.df`:

```
     TLT PCY SHY VTI TIP VNQ VWO RWX VEA DBC GLD
Pct   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

I want to bind the following different-sized data frame named `p.df` to it:

```
          VWO       VEA       VTI
Pct 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.3333333
```

When I execute `rbind.fill(main.df, p.df)` I get:

```
  TLT PCY SHY VTI TIP VNQ VWO RWX VEA DBC GLD
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2  NA  NA  NA   1  NA  NA   1  NA   1  NA  NA
```

which is not what I want. I expected to get:

```
  TLT PCY SHY VTI     TIP VNQ  VWO     RWX VEA    DBC GLD
1   0   0   0   0       0   0    0       0   0     0   0 
2  NA  NA  NA   0.333   NA  NA   0.333  NA  0.333  NA  NA
```

How do I do this? The `dput` of my objects are below.

```
main.df <- structure(list(
  TLT = 0, PCY = 0, SHY = 0, VTI = 0, TIP = 0, VNQ = 0, VWO = 0, RWX = 0, VEA = 0, DBC = 0, GLD = 0),
  .Names = c("TLT", "PCY", "SHY", "VTI", "TIP", "VNQ", "VWO", "RWX", "VEA", "DBC", "GLD"),
  row.names = "Pct", class = "data.frame")

p.df <- structure(list(
  VWO = structure(1L, .Names = "Pct", .Label = c("0.3333333", "VWO"), class = "factor"),
  VEA = structure(1L, .Names = "Pct", .Label = c("0.3333333", "VEA"), class = "factor"),
  VTI = structure(1L, .Names = "Pct", .Label = c("0.3333333", "VTI"), class = "factor")),
  .Names = c("VWO", "VEA", "VTI"), row.names = "Pct", class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would help if you provided a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/271616) using `dput(main.df)` and `dput(p.df)`, but it appears that one or both of those objects contain factor vectors, not numeric vectors. So you need to convert them.

```
main.df[] <- lapply(main.df, function(f) as.numeric(levels(f))[f])
p.df[] <- lapply(p.df, function(f) as.numeric(levels(f))[f])
```

See [How to convert a factor to an integer\numeric without a loss of information](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3418128/271616) for details.

Comment: The put shows you are correct about the factors. I have bitten by this many times in R. That fixed the problem. Thanks!